# How do I group in memory lists?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have a list of `Foo`. Foo has properties `Bar` and `Lum`. Some `Foo`s have identical values for `Bar`. How can I use lambda/linq to group my `Foo`s by `Bar` so I can iterate over each grouping's `Lum`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Deeno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130/how-do-i-group-in-memory-lists#46317),

Enjoy:

```
var foos = new List<Foo> {
   new Foo{Bar = 1,Lum = 1},
   new Foo{Bar = 1,Lum = 2},
   new Foo{Bar = 2,Lum = 3},
};

// Using language integrated queries:

var q = from foo in foos
        group foo by foo.Bar into groupedFoos
        let lums = from fooGroup in groupedFoos
                   select fooGroup.Lum
        select new { Bar = groupedFoos.Key, Lums = lums };

// Using lambdas

var q = foos.GroupBy(x => x.Bar).
            Select(y => new {Bar = y.Key, Lums = y.Select(z => z.Lum)});


foreach (var group in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Lums for Bar#" + group.Bar);
    foreach (var lum in group.Lums)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(lum);
    }
}
```

To learn more about LINQ read [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

```
var q = from x in list
        group x by x.Bar into g
        select g;

foreach (var group in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group " + group.Key);
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Bar);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `select g` line in the query isn't actually necessary; you can just write `from x in list group x by x.Bar`.