# Separate groups of objects based on their properties

Tags: c#, linq

I want to separate an array of my custom object into several arrays, based on the values of their two properties. The struct looks like this:

```
struct MyStruct {

    public string Person {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Command {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now, if I have an array with a few objects:

```
{Person1, cmd1}
{Person1, cmd3}
{Person2, cmd3}
{Person3, cmd2}
{Person2, cmd4}
```

I want to be able to place them into one array for each person, that lists all of the commands for that person:

```
{Person1: cmd1, cmd3}
{Person2: cmd3, cmd4}
{Person3: cmd2}
```

I hope I've made it clear with my descriptions. I would assume that there is an elegant way to do this with LINQ, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130/how-do-i-group-in-memory-lists) - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Please don't create mutable structs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil

Comment: @ani only problem i see here is that the set-properties are public, but other than that the grouping wont change anything on the original structs !?

Comment: @Pauli Østerø: No, they won't. I only brought this up in the interests of best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<MyStruct> sequence = ...

var query = sequence.GroupBy(s => s.Person)
                    .Select(g => new 
                                 { 
                                    Person = g.Key,
                                    Commands = g.Select(s => s.Command).ToArray() 
                                 })
                    .ToArray();
```

A similar query in query syntax:

```
var query = from s in sequence
            group s.Command by s.Person into g
            select new { Person = g.Key, Commands = g.ToArray() };

var queryArray = query.ToArray();
```

Do note that you asked for an array of arrays, but the result here is an array of an anonymous type, one of whose members is an array of strings.

---

On an another note, it's usually [not recommended to create mutable structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil).

Answer (score 0):

I find this the easiest way to do it:

```
yourCollection.ToLookup(i => i.Person);
```